# Error at launch app

Tags: xcode

When I launch app sometimes I get this error and sometimes no:

```
2017-11-10 14:00:37.119701+0000 XXX[768:176399] [DYGLInitPlatform] connection to host has failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"
2017-11-10 14:00:37.123363+0000 XXX[768:176399] aborting: platform initialization failed
(lldb)
```

[image]

What can cause this problem ?

Comment: I added picture for the bug. when finish launches I init Fabric,GMSPlacesClient,GAI,FirebaseApp

Answer (score 32):

There could be some corrupt files in your build folder.

Try running `Clean` (⌘+⇧+K) and `Clean build folder...` ( ⌘+⇧+⌥+K ) and rebuild your application.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the error was related to Launch Screen, most likely it was corrupt.

Deleting the launch screen under General Tab, fixed the issue.